# WiX 3.8 MSI for a 32-bit and a 64-bit machine

Tags: wix, burn, wix3.8

I have [Visual Studio 2012](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2012), WiX 3.8 setup project and [Burn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX#Burn) bootstrapper. Everything works fine if I target a 32-bit machine. I want to create two separate MSI files for 32-bit and 64-bit with localizations. But, I cannot find a 64-bit target option in configuration manager. So, I manually created an x64 target and tried compiling the setup project. But it fails completely. I'm not able to include the following file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension">

    <?include $(var.ProjectDir)\Includes\Variables.wxi ?>

    <Fragment>
        <CustomAction somecustomaction />
        ...
        More custom actions...
        ...
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

The error I get is:

> Error 33 Schema validation failed with the following error at line 1, column 206:
>     The element 'Wix' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi' cannot
>     contain text. List of possible elements expected: 'Bundle Product Module Patch
>     Fragment PatchCreation'. somefile.wxs 2 1 Some.Installer Installer_x64\Some.Installer)

When I remove the include tag, then it compiles. But I need to use such include directives in other files where I reference some variables. I don't really understand the issue here. The include tag works perfectly for 32-bit, then why it is throwing an error if I use it with a 64-bit target? What is the issue here?

Are there any best practices for creating setups for different platforms? I'm also using the Burn bootstrapper and localizations for English and German. I have gone through similar questions on Stack Overflow, but no help so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was in the project file. In my menu *Build* -> *Configuration Manager*, I have set the *Active* build configuration as *Release|x64*. However, Visual Studio din't automatically change my project file content to *Release|x64*.

When I manually edited the project file, I changed the platform to x64, but I missed to change the configuration to *Release*. It was in *Debug|x64* mode and my Visual Studio installation was trying to compile in *Release|x64* mode. Now, the error is resolved and my setup is compiling when I edited my project file manually to *Release|x64*.

However, I still don't understand why candle.exe gave me this error when it was Visual Studio 2012's problem as far as I know. Somebody correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've got pretty much the same setup as you (WiX 3.8, targeting two different platforms, including a "Variables.wxi" file, ...), and it is working perfectly fine. My best guess would be that something is wrong in your Variables.wxi.

To switch some values based on the target platform, use the `$(var.Platform)` variable:

```xml
<!-- x86 / x64 switch -->
<?if $(var.Platform)=x64 ?>

<?define PlatformProgramFilesFolder = "ProgramFiles64Folder" ?>
<?define Win64 = "yes"?>
<?define ProductName = "Datacard EzPrint Plugin (64 bit)" ?>

<?else ?>

<?define PlatformProgramFilesFolder = "ProgramFilesFolder" ?>
<?define Win64 = "no"?>
<?define ProductName = "Datacard EzPrint Plugin" ?>

<?endif ?>
```

Comment: Actually the schema validation error is thrown by candle.exe. I tried commenting the contents of Variables.wxi and gave a empty Variables.wxi. Still it throws the same error. Onemore thing is that I manually edited the project file and changed the platform to x64. Because the settings through VS doesn't get reflected in the project file.

Comment: Updating the project file of the WiX project is something I didn't do. I update my response.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `Include` tag outside the `Wix` tag.

The error is telling you that there is invalid content inside the `Wix` tag.

Comment: Not sure why my answer was down-voted as it explains the error message and solves the issue.

Wix pre-processor commands are typically before the Wix tag.